# Best way to partition by timestamp in a parquet dataframe

Tags: apache-spark-sql, parquet, pyspark

I have a dataframe containing minute level values that looks like below:

```
+---------------------+-------+
|      Timestamp      | Value |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00 |     5 |
| 2018-01-01 00:01:00 |     7 |
| 2018-01-01 00:02:00 |     9 |
| 2018-01-01 00:03:00 |     0 |
| 2018-01-01 00:04:00 |     5 |
| 2018-01-01 00:05:00 |     8 |
| ...                 |   ... |
| ...                 |   ... |
| 2018-12-31 23:58:00 |     8 |
| 2018-12-31 23:59:00 |     7 |
+---------------------+-------+
```

I'd like to save it as a partitioned parquet file so that I can optimize file read.
Later I'd need to select the data for a given duration. For eg: 2018-01-05 00:00:00 to 2018-01-06 00:00:00. I was thinking I can partition this data on year,month,day,hour values as below:

```
df_final = df.withColumn("TimeStamp", to_timestamp(col('TimeStamp'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) \
           .withColumn("year", date_format(col("TimeStamp"), "yyyy")) \
           .withColumn("month", date_format(col("TimeStamp"), "MM")) \
           .withColumn("day", date_format(col("TimeStamp"), "dd")) \
           .withColumn("hour", date_format(col("TimeStamp"), "HH"))
```

This creates a folder structure like this in the resultant parquet

```
└── YYYY
    └── MM
        └── DD
            └── HH
```

But does this partitioning help in read optimization? Also I see that the resulting parquet file is 10x larger in size than the unpartitioned file, on disk.

**What is the best way to partition this file so that I can fetch data for a given duration faster?**

Comment: can you share how many records you are getting at hour level ? if it is less comparatively to date and month, then its better not to go till hour level for partitioning.

Answer (score 2):

Generally when partitioning multilevel, check for number of records that goes into last level, if it is very less, it would be good to stop at previous partition level and use that in our requirements.

Sometimes splitting the files at multi level can be **over optimization** leading to lot of files and disk reads loosing the parquet columnar benefits.